# node/passportjs how to update homepage with welcome user, after logging in and redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

So after landing on the home page, click to sign in, redirect home and at the top I want it to now show the 'welcome [user]'. How do i do that? Basically change from 'login here' to 'welcome user and sign out' after logging in.
I want to add this:

```
h1.text-center.login-title Welcome #{user.firstName}.
```

To my current html/jade after logging in:

```
 extends layout
    block content



    body(style='background-color:black')
   p
    a.fade(href="#")
     img.fade(src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/18140107/large.jpg', 
  height='150', width='200')

  p 
    ul.centered
      li.none
      li Chapter 1 
      li Chapter 2
      li Chapter 3
      li Chapter 4
      li Chapter 5
      li Chapter 6
      li Chapter 7
      li Chapter 8
      li Chapter 9
      li Chapter 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to do with Pug. When you render, simply pass the username to pug and handle it like so:

```
if user.firstName
    h1.text-center.login-title Welcome #{user.firstName}.
else
    h1.text-center.login-title Please Login
```

Read more here: https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html